# Blender GPU Support on Linux with AMD Radeon Pro WX 7100 Mobile

Tags: rendering, gpu, linux

I have a Dell Precision 7740 running on Ubuntu 18.04 Linux with an AMD/ATI Radeon Pro WX 7100 graphics card and a much less powerful Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile). I'd like to utilize the graphics card to help speed up Blender renders. However, under the "System > Cycles Render Devices" setting, I see a "No compatible GPUS found for path tracking. Cycles will render on the CPU."

Given this card and os, what options do I have to optimize my renders and take full advantage of the GPU?

I've encountered the https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/radeon-prorender-blender project. Is this a viable option? (Though I imagine it would be a different rendering engine to learn apart from Cycles and Eevee).

Any thoughts are much appreciated. Thank you

Here is the full output of lspci for the Radeon

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon Pro WX 7100 Mobile] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Ellesmere [Radeon Pro WX 7100]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 205
    Memory at 4200000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8G]
    Memory at 4100000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at b4400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at b4440000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [200] #15
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Capabilities: [2d0] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [320] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [328] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
    Capabilities: [370] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Updated: Added a picture

[image]

Comment: Have you checked in the OpenCL tab? Your graphics card should be supported.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @rjg. The OpenCL tab is what has the error message described above. I've added a picture showing what I see.

Comment: Hardware questions are off-topic for this site as they are highly specific to a particular setup or configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of the lspci you're using the non pro AMD driver which is required for OpenCL at the moment.

The pro driver is available going to AMDs website and searching for drivers for your card. There is a download link for Ubuntu but the latest version they support is Ubuntu 18.04 (x86_64). You might also find you have to use a slightly older kernel version too.

Hopefully at somepoint we will get OpenCL support from the kernel amdgpu driver.

https://www.amd.com/en/support/professional-graphics/radeon-pro/radeon-pro-wx-x100-series/radeon-pro-wx-7100